# How to groupby a column and seperate another column by comma?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe contains columns like this:

```
>>> data['ID']
0        93.0-24
1       127.0-24
2       127.0-22
3       127.0-19
4       127.0-16
5    127.0-22;16
6    127.0-22;16

>>> data['PTM_loc']
0        116
1        150
2        148
3        145
4        142
5        189
6        166
```

I would like to group `PTM_loc` by `ID`, so I did:

```
>>> data.groupby('ID').agg(lambda: ';'.join(x.PTM_loc)).reset_index
```

and then got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/wangyuru/spatialPro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 926, in aggregate
    result = gba.agg()
  File "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/wangyuru/spatialPro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 175, in agg
    return self.agg_list_like()
  File "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/wangyuru/spatialPro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 438, in agg_list_like
    raise ValueError("no results")
ValueError: no results

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/wangyuru/spatialPro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 932, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_frame(func)
  File "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/wangyuru/spatialPro/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 982, in _aggregate_frame
    fres = func(data, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I would like to see a result like:

```
     ID            PTM_loc
0        93.0-24   116
1       127.0-24   150
2       127.0-22   148
3       127.0-19   145
4       127.0-16   142
5    127.0-22;16   189;166
```

Could somebody give me any idea on this error?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you forget the `x` argument in the lambda-function? And the parenthesis at the end: `.reset_index()`?

Comment: I add x to lambda: data.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x.PTM_loc)).reset_index, but it returns error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'PTM_loc'

Answer (score 0):

That's not how [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) works: In case the column `PTM_loc` already contains strings you could do

```py
data = data.groupby('ID').agg(';'.join).reset_index()
```

otherwise do

```py
data = (
    data.assign(PTM_loc=data['PTM_loc'].astype('str'))
    .groupby('ID').agg(';'.join)
    .reset_index()
)
```

If the dataframe has more than the 2 columns shown then use `.agg({'PTM_loc': ';'.join})`.